# How to increase the java precision

Tags: java, double

I am trying to make a Mandelbrot fractal zoom in java, but when the zoom increases, the double does not have enought precision and the image gets pixelated and I can not zoom more. I want to increase the precision or use another data type that allows me to that. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Mandelbrot visualization questions on zooming and coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381336/java-mandelbrot-visualization-questions-on-zooming-and-coloring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

For example -

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.000000000000000000000000000005");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.06");
    BigDecimal c = b.subtract(a);
    System.out.println(c);
```

**EDIT:**
You can control the number of digits to the right of the decimal point using the [setScale()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29) method

```
    BigDecimal p=a.setScale(29, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Thank u! But I can change the precision?

Comment: But, that will give your code an extraordinary performance hit compared to doubles. BigDecimals allocate multiple objects and are immutable, so you are creating new objects for every calculation step.

Comment: @ArthurBacci I have made an update. Have a look.